# Adding MySQL to Application Insights

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, azure, azure-application-insights

Application Insights does not support tracking for MySQL dependencies out of the box, so I would like to add it as my project relies heavily on MySQL.EF6.

Per the documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#track-dependency

It is possible to add tracking, however to avoid having to wrap every call I make to my database, I would like to override the MySQL.EF6 Library functions of `SaveChanges`, `SaveChangesAsync`, `Find`, `FirstOrDefault`, `etc`.

However I am unsure how to accomplish anymore than the `SaveChanges`/`SaveChangesAsync` as they are easily overrideable in my `DbContext` class.

Comment: I am using System.Data.Mysql  which is vanilla mysql ado.net. Can the library System.Data.Mysql track the executred queries and log them to application insights?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using EF6 logging - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx.